# lmxl incremental XML serialisation repeats namespaces

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am currently serializing some largish XML files in Python with lxml. I want to use the incremental writer for that. My XML format heavily relies on namespaces and attributes. When I run the following code

```
from io import BytesIO

from lxml import etree

sink = BytesIO()

nsmap = {
    'test': 'http://test.org',
    'foo': 'http://foo.org',
    'bar': 'http://bar.org',
}

with etree.xmlfile(sink) as xf:
    with xf.element("test:testElement", nsmap=nsmap):
        name = etree.QName(nsmap["foo"], "fooElement")
        elem = etree.Element(name)

        xf.write(elem)

print(sink.getvalue().decode('utf-8'))
```

then I get the following output:

```
<test:testElement xmlns:bar="http://bar.org" 
 xmlns:foo="http://foo.org" 
 xmlns:test="http://test.org">
    <ns0:fooElement xmlns:ns0="http://foo.org"/>
</test:testElement>
```

As you can see, the namespace for `foo` is repeated and not my prefix:

```
<ns0:fooElement xmlns:ns0="http://foo.org"/>
```

How do I make it so lxml only adds the namespace in the root and children use the correct prefix from there? I think I need to use `etree.Element`, as I need to add some attributes to the node.

What did not work:

1) Using `register_namespace`

```
for prefix, uri in nsmap.items():
    etree.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
```

That still repeats, but makes the prefix correct. I do not like it too much, as it changes stuff globally.

2) Specifying the `nsmap` in the element:

```
elem = etree.Element(name, nsmap=nsmap)
```

yields

```
<foo:fooElement xmlns:bar="http://bar.org" 
 xmlns:foo="http://foo.org" 
 xmlns:test="http://test.org"/>
```

for the `fooElement`.

I also looked in the documentation and source code of lxml, but it is Cython so really hard to read and search. The context manager of `xf.element` does not return the element. e.g.

```
with xf.element('foo:fooElement') as e:
    print(e)
```

prints `None`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to produce something close to what you are looking for:

```
from io import BytesIO

from lxml import etree

sink = BytesIO()

nsmap = {
    'test': 'http://test.org',
    'foo': 'http://foo.org',
    'bar': 'http://bar.org',
}

with etree.xmlfile(sink) as xf:
    with xf.element("test:testElement", nsmap=nsmap):
        with xf.element("foo:fooElement"):
            pass

print(sink.getvalue().decode('utf-8'))
```

This produces the XML:

```
<test:testElement xmlns:bar="http://bar.org" xmlns:foo="http://foo.org" xmlns:test="http://test.org"><foo:fooElement></foo:fooElement></test:testElement>
```

The extra namespace declaration is gone, but instead of an immediately closing element, you get a pair of opening and closing tags for `foo:fooElement`.

I looked at the source code of `lxml.etree.xmlfile` and do not see the code there maintaining state that it would then examine to know what namespaces are already declared and avoid declaring them again needlessly. It is possible I just missed something, but I really don't think I did. The point of an incremental XML serializer is to operate without using gobs of memory. When memory is not an issue, you can just create a tree of objects representing the XML document and serialize that. You pay a significant memory cost because the whole tree has to be available in memory until the tree is serialized. By using an incremental serializer, you can dodge the memory issue. In order to maximize the memory savings, the serializer must minimize the amount of state it maintains. If when it produces an element in the serialization, it were to take into account the parents of this element, then it would have to "remember" what the parents were and maintain state. In the worst case scenario it would maintain so much state that it would provide no benefit over just creating a tree of XML objects that are then serialized.

Comment: The question had a bounty, but it seems the OP forgot about it. Perhaps this answer does not solve the problem, but it deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a SubElement:

```
_nsmap={
    'test': 'http://test.org',
    'foo': 'http://foo.org',
    'bar': 'http://bar.org',
}

root = etree.Element(
    "{http://bar.org}test",
    creator='SO',
    nsmap=_nsmap
)

doc = etree.ElementTree(root)
name = etree.QName(_nsmap["foo"], "fooElement")
elem = etree.SubElement(root, name)

doc.write('/tmp/foo.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
print (open('/tmp/foo.xml').read())
```

Returns:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<bar:test xmlns:bar="http://bar.org" xmlns:foo="http://foo.org" xmlns:test="http://test.org" creator="SO">
  <foo:fooElement/>
</bar:test>
```

Comment: How can I use  `SubElement` with `etree.xmlfile`? I do not have a root, and using `xf` gives `TypeError: Argument '_parent' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter)`