# python lxml pkg - how to incrementally write to an XML file using etree.xmlfile AND passing in existing elements?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, kml, xml-namespaces

very new to anything xml related please bear with me - trying to build some code that converts rasters to KML files for google earth.

I've come across the `lxml` package which has made my life easier, but now am facing an issue.

Let's say I've created an element called kml with namespaces:

```
from lxml import etree

version = '2.2'

namespace_hdr = {'gx':f'http://www.google.com/kml/ext/{version}',
                 'kml':f'http://www.opengis.net/kml/{version}',
                 'atom':f'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
                 }

kml = etree.Element('kml', nsmap=namespace_hdr)
```

And I've also created an element called Document:

```
Document = etree.SubElement(kml, 'Document')
```

Now..I have alot of data I want to write and am running into memory issues, so I figured the best approach would be to generate my data to write on the fly and write it as I go, hence the incremental writing.

The approach I'm using is:

```
out_file = 'test.kml'

with etree.xmlfile(out_file, encoding='utf-8') as xf:
        xf.write_declaration()
        with xf.element(kml):
            xf.write(Document)
```

Which returns the error:

```
TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got '_Element'
```

If I change kml to 'kml' it works fine, but obviously does not write the namespaces to the file that I've defined in the kml element.

How is it possible to pass in the kml element instead of a string? Is there a way to do this? Or some other way of incrementally writing to the file?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

FYI - output when using 'kml' is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<kml><Document/>
</kml>
```

I'm trying to achieve the same but with the namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document/>
</kml>
```

Comment: was able to find this but doesnt directly solve my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083828/lmxl-incremental-xml-serialisation-repeats-namespaces/53234674#53234674

Comment: @stovfl  I'm not sure I see how any of those posts help me with my particular issue. Care to shed some light?

Comment: ***"help me with my particular issue"***: Depends if you are open for other approaches. `E-Factory` is another approach to create `XML`.

Comment: Doesn't it rely on storing the entire xml file in memory before writing though?

Comment: @stovfl please if you have any concrete advice for someone who knows zero about XML in general it'd be helpful. I'm not seeing exactly how these posts help me. I'm just trying to go the lxml route because it seems cleaner/easier/the proper way rather than writing a bunch of formatted string blocks using xml syntax

Comment: ***"the entire xml file in memory ..."***: Yes, the simplest use case will do so. Maybe these [`[python] [lxml] SubElement TypeError`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+%5Blxml%5D+SubElement+TypeError) are more related to your issue.